# Text Messaging / Email Interface

Tags: forms, email

I'm looking to design a single interface for composing & sending a message via text and email.

Given email fields/options like subject, bcc, cc are not valid in a text message, I've been leading towards toggling between two composers rather than just enabling/disabling as needed.

I'm curious if anyone has given any thought to this type of interface and if perhaps you have any examples, either prototypes or in the wild?

Here's an example of the current email composer:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My two cents.  Sending an email as a text will normally involve the address starting with all digits and no letters before the @ sign.  You don't tell how the To: is entered, but your form could parse the address and if all numbers precede the @, then show only the Subject, Body, and Send controls. (To validate I sent myself an email to my text address and the subject came through as a bolded top line, and the body followed on the next line not bolded.)

You may also want to inform the user that you have detected the address as a text recipient, and give them the chance to override...

This link also has a list of domains that could stregthen your ability to detect a text recipient. https://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/how-to-send-a-text-from-your-email-account/

Comment: Thanks. This system doesn't involve entering an email address unless you're sending to a BCC or CC. It's a CRM with a predefined recipient, email or phone #.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is, how do I make a message interface that makes sense for both email and text?
Since the recipient can be an email and/or a text message, you can simplify the interface to only use the message portion. The user won't have to enter the Subject because it doesn't matter in a text message, and for an email, you would automatically let the system set it to something predefined.